# datatable convertion error No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments

Tags: c#, datatable, tostring

I have a code to convert data table column to `string` which generates following error

**Code:**

```
string fromDate = datatable.Rows[0]["FromDateAndTime"].ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.000");
```

**Compile Time Error:**

> No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments

just want to get the output as `"2018-11-19 06:00:00.000"` and assign it to `fromDate` variable

Comment: `Convert.ToDateTime(datatable.Rows[0]["FromDateAndTime"]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.000");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `datatable.Rows[0]["FromDateAndTime"]` returns an instance of `object` which *doesn't have* `ToString(format)` method. Let's convert `object` to `DateTime`:

```
string fromDate = Convert
  .ToDateTime(datatable.Rows[0]["FromDateAndTime"])
  .ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.000");
```